# Unable to load multiple asset images in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new in flutter. I want to create a simple gallery app, but am unable to load multiple asset images. I share my code here, can anyone make this code able to load many images?

It gives an exception when the code is executed. I think it should be used *future*, *async* or *await* here but as I said I am new to flutter, so I can't do it.

```
List<ImageDetails> _images= [
  ImageDetails(imagePath: 'assets/images/1.jpg', title: 'Image 1', desc: 'This is image 1 description'),
  ImageDetails(imagePath: 'assets/images/2.jpg', title: 'Image 2', desc: 'This is image 2 description'),
  ImageDetails(imagePath: 'assets/images/3.jpg', title: 'Image 3', desc: 'This is image 3 description'),
  // ImageDetails(imagePath: 'assets/images/4.png', title: 'Image 4', desc: 'This is image 4 description'),
  // ImageDetails(imagePath: 'assets/images/5.png', title: 'Image 5', desc: 'This is image 5 description'),
  // ImageDetails(imagePath: 'assets/images/6.png', title: 'Image 6', desc: 'This is image 6 description'),
];

class HomePage1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height:40),
            Text("Gallery",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Colors.white
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40,),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 30),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30), topRight: Radius.circular(30))
                  ),
                  child: GridView.builder(gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                  ), 
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return RawMaterialButton(
                      onPressed: (){},
                      child: Hero(
                        tag: 'logo$index',
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(_images[index].imagePath),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)
                            )
                          ),
                      )
                      );
                    },
                      itemCount: _images.length,)
                )
              )
          ],
        ),)
    );
  }
}

class ImageDetails{
  final imagePath;
  final title;
  final desc;
  ImageDetails({@required this.imagePath, @required this.title, @required this.desc});
}
```

Comment: Did you include them on `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Yes included. Even 2 or 3 images load accurately, but when I try to add more images to the list then it gives an exception.

Comment: try with `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.

Comment: can you send your exception?

Comment: **Exception Message:**
`Unable to load asset: assets/images/10.jpg`

**Paused on Exception:**
`AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync   package:flutter/.../painting/image_povider.dart
<asynchronous gap>
<asynchronous gap>`

Comment: @Camila The error message talks about `10.jpg` but your code does not mention `10` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, you are right, at the time of this exception I tried some other images in which `10.jpg` existed.